# How can we make a custom thread non modifiable by any other thread?

Tags: java, multithreading

```
public class ThreadDemo  {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager());
    BThread bth=new BThread();
    AThread ath=new AThread();
     }
   }

 class AThread extends Thread {
     AThread(){


}
@Override
public void run() {
    System.out.println("This is A run() function");
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());

   }
  } 
class BThread extends  Thread{
 BThread(){
   System.out.println("In BThread() ");
   System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
   System.out.println(this.getName());
   this.setName("Bth");
   this.start();
   }
@Override
     public void run() {
      System.out.println("This is B run() function");
      System.out.println(Thread.currentThread());
}
```

}

```
  class  MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager{
     public void checkAccess(Thread t) {
        super.checkAccess(t);
        if (t==Thread.currentThread()) {
        return; // thread always can modify itself
      }
     if (t instanceof AThread) {
        throw new SecurityException();
      }
   }
  }
```

output:

```
     In BThread() 
     Thread[main,5,main]
     Thread-0
     This is B run() function
     Thread[Bth,5,main]
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.SecurityException
```

1.Based on Alexei inputs this is what I have tried . Have I implemented it correctly?

2.can you please explain why the exception was thrown when I created AThread object in    main()?

3.I am not modifying AThread but still exception is thrown why?

4.Have I put  System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager()); at right place

Comment: Is there something in particular with the javadocs for the security manager linked to from the javadocs for thread that is confusing you?

Comment: Actually I don't know how can I make a custom thread non modifiable by any other thread.

Comment: Non-modifiable in what sense?

Comment: AS Java Doc says checkAccess() of java.lang.Thread class Determines if the currently running thread has permission to modify this thread. Modifications like changing name, setting priority etc.              In the above example in main thread I can change name ,priority etc of custom thread(AThread).  So How can I make custom thread(AThread) non-modifiable so that main thread or any other thread can't change its attributes like name ,priority etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you have to declare your own SecurityManager:

```
class  MySecurityManager extends SecurityManager{
  public void checkAccess(Thread t) {
    super.checkAccess(t);
    if (t.getId()==0) {// a hack to determine if we are in thread's constructor
       return; 
    }
    if (t==Thread.currentThread()) {
      return; // thread always can modify itself
    }
    if (t is non-modifiable) {
      throw new SecurityException();
    }
  }
```

and install it:

```
System.setSecurityManager(new MySecurityManager());
```

now how to determine if t is non-modifiable? This is up to you. Probably in your project there already is some attribute which describe a thread as non-modifiable. If not, I suggest to declare your own class `NonModifiableThread extends Thread` and check if `t instanceof NonModifiableThread`. Another option is to create special thread group and check if given thread belongs to that group.

UPDATE.

it turns out that Thread's constructor itself calls `setriority()` and so `checkAccess(this)`. To allow another thread to call constructor a way to find out if constructor is running is needed. I added

```
    if (t.getId()==0) {
       return; 
    }
```

to the checkAccess, since id is assigned at the end of constructor. But this is not documented and can change. More reliable solutions are:

- install security manager only after all threads are created, or
- let MySecurityManager keep collection of all non-modifiable threads instead of checking thread's class. Let  constructor of NonModifiableThread register itself at security manager in constructor (after superconstructor finished), and NonModifiableThread.run() method unregister after execution.
- (even better) declare a boolean variable in class NonModifiableThread which is changed in constructor so that MySecurityManager can know if constructor's execution is finished.

Comment: I have tried to implement what you have suggested. Please let me know whether it is  correct or not

Comment: it is correct, but another problem appeared. See my updated answer.